# Let user add a content_script match in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I would like to allow users to click on a "use the extension for this website" button.

It would allow me to don't have matches for my content script at first and add them when the user needs it, is it possible? When a user clicks on the button, the extension will do the job every time the website is visited, not just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While possible (see the second pat of the question), it might be slightly hard to use.

1. A practical solution would be to declare a content script that is always injected (i.e. `<all_urls>` match pattern), but abort execution if the page doesn't match:

   ```
   // content.js

   // Maybe an async check to background / chrome.storage
   if(someCondtion(window.location.host)) startWorking();

   function startWorking() { 
     /* all your main code here */
   }
   ```

   This will cause a scarier permission warning at runtime, but is probably the easiest to implement.
2. Chrome has a [mechanism called "optional permissions"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions) that you can request after install time. You can request a blanket host permission as optional, and then only request origins you need.

   *Warning, the code below was not tested.*

   ```
   // background.js

   function requestHostPermission(host){
     chrome.permissions.request({
       origins: ['*://' + host + '/']
     }, function(granted) {
       // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
       if (!granted) {
         if(chrome.runtime.lastError) console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
         throw Error("Permission denied for host "+host);
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   But then you will have to use some kind of [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), as you cannot use optional permissions with manifest-declared scripts.

Comment: [`chrome.permissions.request`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#method-request) must be called in response to a user gesture. Optional content scripts is a pain to implement, especially if you want to inject in all frames.

Comment: My will was to don't have a content script that is always injected but it really seems hard to manage, thank you for your answer anyway!